# Python append each string from array to a txt file

Tags: python, arrays, json, string, read-write

I have a json file containing this

```json
[
  {
    "results": [
      {
        "names": [
          "Ben",
          "Sam"
        ]
      },
      {
        "names": [
          "John",
          "Max"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to take each string from the names array for each result and append it to a txt file called names.txt, and have each string seperated by a comma. Like this

```
Ben, Sam, John, Max
```

I haven't used Python much so I'm a bit stuck with writing to another file but also on reading from the json file. I currently have

```
with open('results.json') as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
   for item in data['results']:
      names = item['names']
```

And from there is where I'm just about stuck.
Appreciate any help or advice anyone can give, thanks!

Comment: You can open another file and just start writing in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508703/how-to-open-a-file-through-python I would open it before for loop and close it after for loop.

Comment: Also, this will be helpful [Read from file and write to another python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435295/read-from-file-and-write-to-another-python/50435495) See the method with 19 votes. It is using the with keyword which is preferable in my opinion.

Comment: @Goion Thanks so much man, both of those look like exactly what I need for accessing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight problem with your JSON, the comma after `"Max"` makes it invalid.

If you fix that you can use this code to read the file, get a list of the names and write them to another file, `results_names.txt`

```py
import json

with open('results.json') as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)

names = []

for item in data[0]['results']:
    names.extend(item['names'])

with open('results_names.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(', '.join(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative method which combines opening and closing related files

```
import json

with open('results.json','r') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    data = json.load(f_in)
    for i in list(range(0,len(data)+1)):
        s=data[0]['results'][i]['names']
        if i>0:
            f_out.write(',')
        f_out.write(','.join(s))
```

where we should be careful when putting comma between every seperate objects