# Execute script on one text file, and create new text file with output without cmd

Tags: python, file, io, txt

Title is pretty self-explanatory. Currently I have:

```
with open('dwarf_fort.txt') as f:
    for minerals in f:
        mining_rig()
```

I need it to go from 'dwarf_fort.txt', execute the program and append the output into a new file. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want to write the output of the file to a different file?

Comment: Yes please. I'm aware of using cmd for 'oldfile.txt > newfile.txt' but how can it be done within the script itself?

Comment: You open the second file as well as the `dwarf_fort` file, read from one and write to another. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435835/3730626

Comment: @M B Hi thanks for the help. I have done this and when I open the output file it is blank. What's happened?

Comment: I have added an answer with working code. Compare the code from the answer below with your code and see what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open('dwarf_fort.txt') as f, open('out_f.txt', mode='w') as f1:
    for minerals in f:
        f1.write(minerals)
```

If the output file is still blank, do some checks:

- Make sure the `dwarf_fort.txt` is in the same directory as the .py script.
- Make sure the `dwarf_fort.txt` is not blank
- Make sure your script is in a directory that is writeable to (so that the `out_f.txt` that gets created can be written to)